# Algorithm for recursively linked objects

Tags: algorithm, recursion, go

I'm maintaining a small program that goes through documents in a Neo4j database and dumps a JSON-encoded object to a document database. In Neo4j—for performance reasons, I imagine—there's no real data, just ID's.

Imagine something like this:

```
posts:
    post:
        id: 1
        tags: 1, 2
        author: 2
        similar: 1, 2, 3
```

I have no idea why it was done like this, but this is what I have to deal with. The program then uses the ID's to fetch information for each data structure, resulting in a proper structure. Instead of `author` being just an `int`, it's an `Author` object, with name, email, and so on.

This worked well until the `similar` feature was added. `Similar` consists of ID's referencing other posts. Since in my loop I'm building the actual post objects, how can I reference them in an efficient manner? The only thing I could imagine was creating a cache with the posts I already "converted" and, if the referenced ID is not in the cache, put the current post on the bottom of the list. Eventually, they will all be processed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach you're proposing won't work if there are cycles of `similar` relationships, which there probably are.

For example, you've shown a post `1` that is similar to a post `2`. Let's say you come across post `1` first. It refers to post `2`, which isn't in the cache yet, so you push post `1` back onto the end of the queue. Now you get to post `2`. It refers to post `1`, which isn't in the cache yet, so you push post `2` back onto the end of the queue. This goes on forever.

You can solve this problem by building the post objects in two passes. During the first pass, you make `Post` objects and fill them with all the information except for the `similar` references, and you build up a `map[int]*Post` that maps ID numbers to posts. On the second pass, for each post, you iterate over the `similar` ID numbers, look up each one in the map, and use the resulting `*Post` values to fill a `[]*Post` slice of similar posts.

Comment: What if the "similar" field needs subsets of the Post struct? Like, fewer fields. Instead of referencing, should i create a mapper?

Comment: If the `similar` data is a list of values, I think you would definitely want to represent the values with a slice. What you put in the slice is up to you. Each element could be a `map[string]bool`, for example, that stores a set of field names.